# How to disallow commerce checkout if no payment method is available?

Tags: 7, commerce

With Drupal Commerce and Commerce Payment, when no payment method is available on the checkout, it displays this message: `Payment is not required to complete your order.` and the customer is still able to finish the checkout.

It's probably trivial, but I can't find a solution that doesn't involve calling a hook in a custom module.

The best solution would to actually display a webform when no payment method is available.

Comment: Why would your payment method wont be available ?

Comment: Based on different amount and location rules, the order should be invoiced first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The core payment module offers this option in the checkout pane's settings form.